# How to add digital signature to excel file in java to protect excel file. Does POI support adding digital signature?

Tags: apache-poi, digital-signature

I had already tried some code from google

```
//code to create private key and x509
//.. 
//..

SignatureConfig signatureConfig = new SignatureConfig();
             signatureConfig.setKey((PrivateKey) key);
             signatureConfig.setSigningCertificateChain(Collections.singletonList(x509));
             OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open("DigitalSignatureTest.xlsx", PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
             signatureConfig.setOpcPackage(pkg);

// adding the signature document to the package
SignatureInfo si = new SignatureInfo();
si.setSignatureConfig(signatureConfig);
si.confirmSignature();
```

It throws exception , cannot resolve element with ID idSignedProperties

Can someone provide a working code for digitally signing of excel files?

Comment: Is `DigitalSignatureTest.xlsx` a valid Excel sheet before you try to sign it?
To answer your subject question, yes POI supports XML signatures, but this feature seems to be hardly used, so there might be a lot of cases which I haven't tested yet ...
Can you provide your test file and maybe your keystore in a bugzilla entry (alternatively per mail (kiwiwings at apache.org) to me)?

Comment: I had sent my code over mail. Appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to solve this . The issue was with version of the jars used. Promoting to higher version of jars solved the issue